# Self created Filters in angularJS 1.5 with example?

Tags: html, angularjs

All together HTML with js work for custom filter. Here I am taking example of books with click filter when we click on subject name it filter

```
angular.module('testApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
            name: 'Hindi'
        },
        {
            name: 'Math'
        },
        {
            name: 'English'
        },
        {
            name: 'Science'
        },
        {
            name: 'Computer'
        },
        {
            name: 'History'
        },

    ];
    $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = x;
    }
});
```

HTML Code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <font size="3" color="red">
        <p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>
    </font>

    <div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Subject Name</th>

            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy">
                <td>{{x.name}}</td>

            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: First of all it is not angularJS 1.5 when you include angular 1.6.4 as library. Second you are not using a custom filter, but rather just a ng-click and set a scope variable. Also there is no real question. Maybe you can provide a jsfiddle or some information what is not working

Comment: What is your question?